# Regex Extract matched string from URL (working, better solution?)

Tags: javascript, regex, performance

So i essentially i want to test that a url matches a domain, and then return back (if it exists) the last occurance a (dash delimited) group w 4-5 characters and 3-5 numbers.

```
function testLink (link) {
  var reg = /test.com.*-([A-Z]{4,5}[0-9]{3,5})/i;
  return try { link.match(reg)[1] } catch(e) { false }
}

testLink('http://www.test.com/something-test-C34-CAA0004-CJFE348');
==> CJFE348
```

the match returns array with full test string and then my pattern. if it fails the try catch will be hit and return false. this seems to work, but not sure if there is a better way? also not sure if the regex is bullet proof for my conditions. im building a feature that will need to scan lots and lots of links so i want to find best/fastest solution

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. The `try...catch` is useless, `match` doesn't throws exceptions. If it doesn't match, it returns `null`. Moreover, `try` is *not* a function, so it doesn't return anything. You can try the ternary operator `?...:`.

Comment: null[1] would throw an exception, but ya probably dont need try catch in general. i didnt test that accidentally, i did try catch by itself and assumed it would return value

Comment: Yep, sorry, I got confused by that syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex would match domains ending with test...

```
www.softwaretest.com/.....
www.valvetest.com/....
```

Also,you have not escaped `.` with `[.]` or `\.`,so it would also match

```
www.test1com.com/...
www.testXcom.com/....
```

---

Your regex should be

```
https?://(www[.])?test[.]com.*-([A-Z]{4,5}[0-9]{3,5})
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use `\.` to escape dots?

Comment: @MaxArt indeed but that looks ugly..:)

Comment: so i cant guarantee www, what about (^|[.])test[.]com

Comment: i made slight change, this seems to work great. lets bare domain/http/https work. thanks for your help  --- /(^|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)(www[.])?test[.]com.*-([A-Z]{4,5}[0-9]{3,5})/i

Comment: or just /^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(www[.])?test[.]com.*-([A-Z]{4,5}[0-9]{3,5})/i

Comment: @ndreckshage yes..but it depends where you are using it..are you matching urls in an html or an individual url..in later case its ok to use it

Answer (score 1):

The function is fine, but there's no need to use `try-catch`:

```
function testLink (link) {
  var your_match = link.match(/test.com.*-([A-Z]{4,5}[0-9]{3,5})/i);
  // Not sure why do you want to return "false" rather than "null"
  return your_match ? your_match[1] : null;
}
```

Comment: May I suggest `return your_match && your_match[1];`?